# Changing Expression during a multi operator calculation

Tags: java, string, calculator

I am trying to make a string calculator that will follow the orders of operation.

How would I go about changing the expression as the expression is being evaluated?

For example, 2 + 3 * 3. How would I go about changing it to 2 + 9 after I computed the results of 3 * 3?

I tried to use a character array but I'm not sure how to use it to replace all three characters with just "9".

Comment: Don't change the expression as you go, it's a dead-end road. Look up "recursive descent parser" and take it from there.

Comment: Try an ArrayList<Character> and .remove()?